# print multiple copies in php using window.print

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to print multiple copies of just a product name on a sticker. No of copies would be passed by popup onto print.php page.
 I tried using while loop to use window.print but it prints only 1 copy.
heres my code:

```
function PrintPage() {
     var count = <?echo $prnt?>;
while (count >0){
       // alert("print");
    window.print();
    count--;
    
}
 window.close();

}
document.loaded = function(){
    
}
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    PrintPage()
    setTimeout(function(){ window.close() },750)
});
```

used alert to debug if loops works, its showing.
I know this is regularly asked question ,however, I tried and its not working for me. Please help

Comment: Just create a PDF with multiple pages. Or make a page with two copes and page break. What you are trying will not work well on all browsers

Comment: Could get pretty annoying, if a website could trigger a hundred print dialogs in a row, so I am guessing browsers probably prevent this. Create a page that holds the content to be printed X times instead, and then print that once? If you need each on a new page, then use CSS to format it accordingly, i.e. `break-before`/`break-after` ...?